# Tilde character in the brackets

Tags: matlab, syntax

In MATLAB, what does the following code do:

```
[m, ~]=func_returning_matrix()
```

What does the tilde operator, ~, do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Matlab it means don't assign the corresponding output argument(s) from the function on the rhs of the assignment. So, if `func_returning_matrix` returns 2 arguments, the expression will assign the first to the variable `m` and forget the second. If `func_returning_matrix` returns 3 (or more) arguments, then the expression will drop the second and all later outputs from the function.

Comment: Note that this functionality is most commonly used for omitting the first output argument when only subsequent outputs are desired. For example, if you wanted only the index of the maximum value from an array, `[~,idx] = max(A)` would give you the value without the use of a throwaway variable for the actual maximum value.