# What does this symbol ~ do in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am student in physics and they gave me a program in matlab to get some results. Is some point matlab crashes and indicates the problem at this line:

```
[~,idx] = min(cf(:));
```

error message is:
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

I want to ask what does ~ do in matlab? At my search in google I found that ~ is the approximately symbol. So what reason does it have to be there?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? The tilde-to-ignore-output was only introduced [in R2009b](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/).  If you're using a version earlier than that it will throw an error.

Comment: Just to confirm, if you run the code with `dbstop if error`, can you confirm that `cf` is a simple matrix and that the error also occurs if you run the code separately?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tilde character in the brackets (matlab code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913325/tilde-character-in-the-brackets-matlab-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde in that expression is used to [ignore the first return value](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html) from the `min` function. That syntax has only been around for a few years, it's possible the error is occurring because you're using an older version of MATLAB.

Try replacing the `~` with `idx`. That'll cause the second return value to overwrite the first one, and will be functionally equivalent to the code you've posted.

---

In other contexts, `~` is the [logical not operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html) and `~=` is a logical comparison operator for testing inequality.

Comment: Like @Praetorian said it to ignore value instead of creating a junk variable. But you can just try : [junk, idx] = min(cf(:)); to obtain the index of the minimum value in your matrix.

Comment: Though using [idx, idx] as output is fine from a technical point of view, I find this makes the code harder to read. Hence I would recommend using a different name like 'junk', 'XXX', or 'ans'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been a real help!

Answer (score 0):

`min` function can return two values, where the first is the minimum value of the input array and the second is the index corresponding to the minimum value. Sometimes you don't really need the actual minimum value, so for the first return value you just put `~` there as a place holder, without assigning it to a specific variable.

The error is probably associated with an unbalanced statement in preceding lines of the function call you are showing